# OS system dependent build with net.core (Windows and Linux Docker)

Tags: linux, windows, docker, .net-core

I have different dlls for net.core from a tool vendor for Linux and Windows. (dll and so)

In the IDE I need the Windows version. The application itself will later run in Docker under Linux.

My idea is to create a nuget package that contains both versions and the build can be chosen via a switch.

I am looking for an approach how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is what you gonna need:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation?view=netcore-3.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.osdescription?view=netcore-3.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.isosplatform?view=netcore-3.1

**[Update]**

missunderstood your question a little bit , but you can check the os version and the dynamically load the assembly with 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load?view=netcore-3.1

I would suggest to implement an interface for this library so you can inject the correct implementation for the running OS after loading the dll. (e.g. Autofac with using Assembly Scanning https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html)